# Installing .NET4.0 app on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, .net-4.0, windows-server-2008

am trying to install GitAspx application which requires .Net Framework 4.0 on Windows Server 2008 with IIS7. After creating site in IIS Manger and selecting 4.0 Integrated pool, I have an error Page while browsing mainpage with code 404.14. It says:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>   The Web server is configured to not
>   list the contents of this directory.

The directory of application contains **Global.asax** file.

I have run aspnet_regiis from v4.0 directory with various sets of parameters, but its doesn't help.
 Selecting another pool (Classic or v2.0) doens't help too.

Can anybody explain what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like IIS is configured to accept default documents (like index.aspx, index.html, etc.) that you do not provide in your folder.

Either provide such a file or add your default document file name to the list of accepted default documents in the IIS configuration.

[Here is an example of how to configure IIS](http://martinnormark.com/configuring-iis-7-default-document-from-web-config).

Comment: Question was solved by setting .net-v4.0-intergated pool from standart set as pool for this application.